# IDE for Java + Rhino with debugging and profiling facility for js scripts using custom js libraries and the complete JCL?

Tags: java, javascript, autocomplete, ide, rhino

I have a Java application that extensively uses javascripting to let us quickly configure its different modules in different ways. Internally the scripts are simply compiled by Rhino, and can use any object from the Java Class Library, custom Java classes or other javascript files as well. But our scripts are becoming more and more complex to the point where we need to debug and profile those scripts to see which Java method call slows down a script.

So is there any IDE that provides the following in this context :

- javascript code completion, taking into account the JCL and our custom Java/js code.
- javascript debugger
- javascript profiler

I took a look at Eclipse / JSDT, but it's geared towards web development, so code completion is limited to javascript native objects and the DOM (the latter being useless in the context). I know I can add code completion for custom js code by adding our scripts as user libraries. But I'm not sure how to integrate Rhino debugger, and it doesn't seem like there is a profiler that can handle Rhino's compiled code.